# Encoding in Scene Builder

Tags: javafx-2

I generate an FXML file with Scene Builder. I need it to contain some cirillic text.

When i edit this file with Scene Builder i can see normal cirillic letters [(screen 1)](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/45422316/scene%20builder/sb1.PNG)

After compileing and running my program with this FXML file, i can see not cirillic letters, but some artefacts [(screen 2)](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/45422316/scene%20builder/sb4.PNG)

But, as you can see on the [screen 3](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/45422316/scene%20builder/sb2.PNG), its xml file encoding is UTF-8. Also, you can see there that it is saved in ANSI.

I've tried to open it with other editors (default eclipse and sublime text 2) and they shoen wrong encoding either. ([screen 4](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/45422316/scene%20builder/sb5.PNG) and [screen 5](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/45422316/scene%20builder/sb3.PNG))

At first i've tried to convert it from ansi to utf-8 (with notepad++).

After that eclipse and sublime text 2 started display cirillic letters as they must be.

But. Scene builder gave an error, when i've tried to open this file with it:

```
Error loading file 
C:\eclipse\workspace\pr\src\main\java\ru\i\ava\pr\test.fxml.
C:\eclipse\workspace\pr\src\main\java\ru\i\ava\pr\test.fxml:1: ParseError 
at [row,col]:[1,1]
Message: Content is not allowed in prolog.
```

And java compiler gave me an error:

```
 июн 08, 2012 8:11:03 PM javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader logException
 SEVERE: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,1]
 Message: Content is not allowed in prolog.
 /C:/eclipse/workspace/pr/target/classes/ru/i/ava/pr/test.fxml:1
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
 at ru.i.ava.pr.PrFX.start(PrFX.java:22)
 at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$5.run(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4.run(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$3.run(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
 at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$100(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$2$1.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

 Exception in Application start method
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.access$000(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
 Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at    
 [row,col]:[1,1]
 Message: Content is not allowed in prolog.
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
at ru.i.ava.pr.PrFX.start(PrFX.java:22)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$5.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$3.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$100(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$2$1.run(Unknown Source)
... 1 more
    Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,1]
    Message: Content is not allowed in prolog.
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.next(Unknown Source)
at javax.xml.stream.util.StreamReaderDelegate.next(Unknown Source)
... 14 more
```

So, i've converted it back to ANSI.

And, having this file in ANSI, changed its "artefacted" text to cirillic letters manually.

Now i can see normal text when i run my program, but when i open this fixed file via Scene Builder,

Scene Builder shows me some "artefacted" text [(screen 7)](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/45422316/scene%20builder/sb7.PNG).

So, how can i fix this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just found that [new version](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/devpreview-1429449.html) of Scene Builder does not have such problem.

Comment: Victoria, please, accept your own answer as you have found out solution yourself.